# Select Query to find difference

Tags: sql

I am fairly new to sql.  my question is how do I group by a field and then determine the difference between values in a column.  for example.

claim# amount

```
1. c3101    50000
2. c3101    19000
3. c1307    30000
4. c1307    14000
5. c3104    75000
6. c3104     0
7. c1313    5000
8. c1313   10000
```

expected results

```
1. c3101    -31000
2. c1307     -26000
3. c1313     5000
```

i need to find the diffence between amounts relative to a claim number. so for c3101 i started at 50000 and went to 19000 so the transaction to get to 19000 would be -31000. c3104 would be ignored

Comment: Are there always exactly 2 rows per `claim` number? What RDBMS are you using? How are "first" and "last" defined? Does the column with values `1,2,3, ...8` exist in your table? If so what is its name?

Comment: [What, exactly, have you tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com)

Comment: Which RDBMS are you using?

Comment: @Christopher Robinson I've provided an updated answer that produced your results using the default order for MS SQl and MYSQL.

Comment: no there can be many rows per claim; I am using access; first and last are not defined; no just line numbers;  I have tried nested query but don't know how to group by claim number;  i will try to post what I have tried;

Answer (score 2):

You can use group by and sum to find the total values for a specific claim.
Finding the difference cannot be done unless you specify which claim amount was the first (unless you use the insertion/default order).
If we know which is first we could subtract with the other amount (or amount(s)).

If there are only two entries for each claim you can get the absolute different between the `first()` and `last()` entries.

```
select claim, abs(last(amount) - first(amount)) from claims group by claim;
```

You can also get the non-absolute difference, based on insertion order:

```
select claim, (last(amount) - first(amount)) from claims group by claim;
```

### Update

As `first()` and `last()` are not supported in many DBs, below are alternatives:

**MySQL**

```
select distinct claim, 
(select amount from claims c1 where c1.claim = c2.claim limit 1,1) -
(select amount from claims c1 where c1.claim = c2.claim limit 0,1) as "Difference"
from claims c2;
```

SQLFiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/2e62a0/15

**MS SQL**

For MS SQL, as it is quite more difficult to get the bottom X records from a set, I make use of the `average()` function:

```
   SELECT claim, ((avg(amount)*2) -
                 (SELECT top 1 amount
                  FROM claims c2
                  WHERE c2.claim = c.claim))-
  (SELECT top 1 amount
   FROM claims c2
   WHERE c2.claim = c.claim)
FROM claims c
GROUP BY claim;
```

which is further simplified to:

```
SELECT claim,
       2* ( avg(amount) -
             (SELECT top 1 amount
              FROM claims c2
              WHERE c2.claim = c.claim))
FROM claims c
GROUP BY claim;
```

SQL Fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/2e62a/28

Comment: Wait...which RDBMS supports `first()` and `last()`? Wouldn't those have to be window functions?

Comment: If you check http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aggregate_function , in the SQL aggregate function section you will see them. Unfortunately though I'm aware of `access` supporting it, which is why I have been updating the answer with examples from other DBs... but unfortunately the specific capability to either limit, or get top/bottom is vendor specific so syntax changes.

Comment: @Jack Maney Did my best to come up with solutions for two of the most popular DBs... (especially with data missing a key).